# Definition of "particle" in QM and QFT

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, definition, second-quantization

To sum up;

- In Classical Physics, particles can be defined [as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle)

> ... particles (or corpuscule in older texts) is a small localized object to which can be ascribed several physical or chemical properties such as volume, density or mass.

- In Quantum Mechanics, they are described by the wave function where particles can be thought as the collapse of the wave function.
- In Quantum Field Theory, they are nothing but the quantum excitations in the corresponding field.
- In String Theory, they are vibrating strings at different frequencies.
- In Mathematical Physics, particles can be defined [as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_group)

> For example, in one way of rigorously defining exactly what a subatomic particle is, Sheldon Lee Glashow has expressed that "Particles are at a very minimum described by irreducible representations of the Poincaré group.

Even more definitions of what a particle is can be given from a perspective of Condensed Matter and etc.

**Edit**

Where should one abandon the wave function description of particle and should start thinking about it as quantum excitations? Where should one draw this line? (e.g. when one considers pair production and annihilation?, multi-particle systems?, relativistic particles?) In other words, where does the wave function description of particle breaks down?

Comment: Can you rephrase this as a Q&E, so that the question remains clear: "what is the definition of a particle in each physical theory?" And the answer (to be provided also by you) to be edited by anybody who can rephrase it better/more accurately?

Comment: I am not sure i understand your dilemma. Probably any object in our world can have more than one definition. E.g. what is a table? Definitions depend on context. Aren't you really asking in what limit string theory becomes qft, qft becomes qm etc?

Comment: They can have more than one definition but I think it's important to know where one starts and one ends. You asked it better than I did, yes in what limit quantum mechanical wave function picture for a particle can be replaced by quantum field theoretical excitation picture?

Comment: @Monopole how long is a piece of string?

Comment: @Обжоров I don't understand the relevance of your last question. What does it have to do with the length of a string?

Comment: @Monopole It means that it once again depends on the context and what your are trying to work out. At what velocities do you need special relativity and not classical mechanics? For a start it depends with what accuracy you are targeting. But, somehow I feel you already know all of that.